# Is labelling images with polygon better than square?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo, multilabel-classification, darknet

I aim to make an object detection model and I labelled data with a square box
If I label the images with polygon, will it be better than square?

(labelling on image of people wearing safety helmet or not)

I did try label with polygon shape on a few images and after export txt file for YOLO
why it has only 4 points in the text file as same as labelled with a square shape
how those points will represent an area that I label accurately?

```
1 0.573748 0.018953 0.045332 0.036101
1 0.944520 0.098375 0.108931 0.167870
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have labeled your object in a polygonial format, but when you had made a conversion to YOLO-format the information in the labelings has reduced. The picture below shows how I suppose has happend; [image]

...where you have done polygon shape annotation (black shape). But, the conversion has "searched" the smallest x-value from the polygonial coordinate points and smallest y-value from corresponding polygonial coordinate points. And, those are the "first two" values of your YOLO-format. The same logic has happend with the "width" and "heigth" -parameters.

A good description about the idea behind the labelling and dataset is shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6s61a_pqfM.

In short; for your purpose (for efficiency) I propose you make fast & convenient annotation using rectangles only - no time consuming polygon annotation.

Comment: just for completeness, i think there is a small error in your image. in Yolo X and Y are not relative to the top left corner, but rather the center of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The YOLO you are using very likely only has square annotation support.
See [this video](https://youtu.be/S1UUR4FlJ84?t=420) showing square vs polygon quality of results for detection, and the problem of annotation time required to create custom data sets.

To use polygonal masks can I suggest switching to use [YOLOv3-Polygon](https://github.com/ming71/yolov3-polygon) or [YOLOv5-Polygon](https://github.com/XinzeLee/PolygonObjectDetection)